# send data from python script to python script inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, networking, ipc

I have running a python script at my host system and a python script inside my docker container. How can I send data from my python script at my host system to my python script inside my docker container? I would open a port at my docker container and use UDP messages to send the data to the docker container. I do not know if this is the best solution? What are the possibilities and the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using UDP? TCP is more reliable. Also, there is the `pyzmq` offering messaging above TCP.

Comment: ...or HTTP is a pretty common option too.

Comment: it all comes down to how 2 python scripts communicate over the network. if you can solve this then the container is just one of the "ends". If you can't solve this yet then docker will just confuse things even more so maybe first try to solve this.